# How to exclude multiple files from processResources Gradle task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have to exclude files of type xsl and xsd from the processResources gradle task. Currently i have only excluded the xsl files and my build.gradle snippet for that looks something like the below:

```
processResources {
filesNotMatching("**/*.xsl") {
    expand(project.properties)
}
dependsOn versionInfo
}
```

I want to exclude files with extension xsd as well by including the pattern of the package in which the generated classes belong. I have come to understand that the filesNotMatching function does not take multiple arguments. What is the alternative to doing this?

Comment: What you have come to understand is incorrect: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:filesNotMatching(java.lang.Iterable,%20org.gradle.api.Action). Or rather, it's correct, but the argument can be an Iterable of patterns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`filesNotMatching` can take a `String` pattern or an [`Iterable<String>`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#filesNotMatching-java.lang.Iterable-org.gradle.api.Action-). That means the code can be:

```
processResources {
    filesNotMatching(["**/*.xsl", "**/*.xsd"]) {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
    dependsOn versionInfo
}
```